# iOS Pinch Zoom on Map with Image Overlay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pinchzoom, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Want to know if it is possible to Pinch Zoom on a map that has an image overlay on top of it?  So for example, in the app is a map.  I want to add an image on top of the map yet still retain the functionality of zooming in/out of the map using the uipinchgesturerecognizer.  I can add buttons to programmatically zoom, but I would prefer to pinch zoom if I can.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize `hittest` to check if a pinch gesture on overlay image intersects with mapView. If it does, pass the gesture to mapView.